# Add Tag When Work Item Created

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

Can I add a tag to a VSTS work item when it is created?

When I tried to use the `Set the value of` it doesn't allow `Tag`.

[image: create rule screenshot]

Reference: VSTS Docs -> [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/custom-rules?view=vsts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in-the-box. You could use a service hook to accomplish it (on work item created, call your service, service goes and updates the work item).

Let me give you some food for thought, though: If every work item has a tag, isn't that the same as *no work item has a tag*? It's the same concept as "if everything is high priority, nothing is high priority".

I have no idea what you're doing with this tag, but if the idea is that everything starts out tagged and you remove the tag when some condition is met, try **adding** a tag when the condition is met.

Comment: I'll bite, 
Set the rule as follows:

If value of some dropdown field equals 'A'
Add tag 'A' to the created work item

Now when a work item is modified and tag equals 'A', send out a web hook.

Thats actually the solution I had in mind but work item rules are limited in ADO :/